how can i access all massege notification with flutter
Basically, I want to use Flutter to store every phone number and SMS. Which library would be appropriate for this? or any functionally to access when a sms notification pushed..
how to access all sms at phone with fluter

May be you can look at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_broadcasts m i think you can check it and work on it

Use the package at https://pub.dev/packages/sms_advanced
then create a new sms query like   SmsQuery query = new SmsQuery(); after that you can get all your sms messages like await query.getAllSms();

my main focus is to access the bank sms but by this librery i am getting sms without bank sms
